# Jest test fails if using Ramda reduce but passes with native

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, ramda.js, babel-jest

I have noticed that if I use `ramda` sometimes I get issues while trying to write `Jest` tests for the methods I am exporting. I have boiled the problem down the following test and two basic reducer functions. I have posted them on `gist` as to not clog up this question with the code.

https://gist.github.com/beardedtim/99aabe3b08ba58037b20d65343ed9d20

I get the following error with the `ramda` reducer:

```
      ● counter usage › counter counts the words and their index in the given list of words

    expect(received).toEqual(expected)

    Expected value to equal:
      [{"count": 3, "indexes": [0, 2, 4], "value": "a"}, {"count": 1, "indexes": [1], "value": "b"}, {"count": 1, "indexes": [3], "value": "c"}]
    Received:
      [{"count": 15, "indexes": [0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4], "value": "a"}, {"count": 5, "indexes": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], "value": "b"}, {"count": 5, "indexes": [3, 3, 3, 3, 3
], "value": "c"}]
```

Which leads me to believe that `ramda`'s reduce is keeping some sort of state or sharing `words` with each other. I am unsure of how that is happening. Anyone know of what I should be googling or some docs/examples of others handling this?

Comment: This looks like the implementation of `reduce` for arrays https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/src/internal/_reduce.js#L7-L19

Comment: @elclanrs thank you for pointing out that `reduce` does not take an index. Adding the index does not change my test still failing for some reason. I have updated the gist to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the state Array (`final`) is hardwired into `reduceWithIndex`. All calls to this function share the same `final` array.

Try this:

```
import { reduce, addIndex } from 'ramda';

const reduceWithIndex = addIndex(reduce)((final, word, index) => {
  const found = final.find(({ value }) =>
    value.toLowerCase() === word.toLowerCase()
  );
  if (found) {
    found.count++;
    found.indexes.push(index);
  } else {
    final.push({
      value: word.toLocaleLowerCase(),
      count: 1,
      indexes: [index],
    });
  }

  return final;
});

export default words => reduceWithIndex([], words);
```

Answer (score 1):

The diagnosis from Thomas is spot-on.  But I would choose a slightly different fix:

```
import { reduce, addIndex, append } from 'ramda';

const reduceWithIndex = addIndex(reduce);

export default reduceWithIndex((final, word, index) => {
  const found = final.find(({ value }) =>
    value.toLowerCase() === word.toLowerCase()
  );
  if (found) {
    found.count++;
    found.indexes.push(index);
    return final;
  }
  return append({
      value: word.toLocaleLowerCase(),
      count: 1,
      indexes: [index],
  }, final);
}, []);
```

Functional programming is about many things, but one of the most important ones is immutable data structures.  Although nothing prevents you from mutating the accumulator object and passing it back in your reducer function, I find it poor style.  Instead, always return a new object and you won't have such problems.  All of Ramda's functions are built on this principle, so when using `append`, you automatically get a new list.

I would also recommend altering the `if`-block to avoid internal mutation of the `found` object.  I'll leave that as an exercise, but feel free to ping if it's difficult to do.

You can see the difference between the **[original solution](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20reduceWithIndex%20%3D%20addIndex%28reduce%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20counter%20%3D%20reduceWithIndex%28%28final%2C%20word%2C%20index%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20found%20%3D%20final.find%28%28%7B%20value%20%7D%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20value.toLowerCase%28%29%20%3D%3D%3D%20word.toLowerCase%28%29%0A%20%20%29%3B%0A%20%20if%20%28found%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20found.count%2B%2B%3B%0A%20%20%20%20found.indexes.push%28index%29%3B%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20final.push%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20word.toLocaleLowerCase%28%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20count%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20indexes%3A%20%5Bindex%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%29%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20return%20final%3B%0A%7D%2C%20%5B%5D%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20words%20%3D%20%5B%27a%27%2C%20%27b%27%2C%20%27a%27%2C%20%27c%27%2C%20%27a%27%5D%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log%28counter%28words%29%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28counter%28words%29%29%3B%0A%0A)** and the **[altered version](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.22.1#?const%20reduceWithIndex%20%3D%20addIndex%28reduce%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20counter%20%3D%20reduceWithIndex%28%28final%2C%20word%2C%20index%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20found%20%3D%20final.find%28%28%7B%20value%20%7D%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20value.toLowerCase%28%29%20%3D%3D%3D%20word.toLowerCase%28%29%0A%20%20%29%3B%0A%20%20if%20%28found%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20found.count%2B%2B%3B%0A%20%20%20%20found.indexes.push%28index%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20final%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20return%20append%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20word.toLocaleLowerCase%28%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20count%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20indexes%3A%20%5Bindex%5D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20final%29%3B%0A%7D%2C%20%5B%5D%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20words%20%3D%20%5B%27a%27%2C%20%27b%27%2C%20%27a%27%2C%20%27c%27%2C%20%27a%27%5D%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log%28counter%28words%29%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28counter%28words%29%29%3B%0A%0A)** in the Ramda REPL.